# Where Roundcube saving users data and settings

Tags: roundcube

I using HTTPSocket and DA_Emails Library to creating a signup script in Direct Admin account.
and i want to saving user data when signup like first name , last name , nickname ect.
but i don't now where Roundcube saving users data and settings.

Answer (score 1):

in mysql roundcube_db -> users